# New tag needs a synonym, or to be toasted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15295242/revisions), I replaced the new tag [zf2](/questions/tagged/zf2) with the tag [zend-framework2](/questions/tagged/zend-framework2). The question and the user's edit to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zf2/info) clearly indicate that Zend Framework 2 is the meaning of that new tag.

However, as you can see in the revision history, the user reverted my tag edit. I left a comment explaining why I made that change, but I'm not editing the tags back.

So, do we need to make a synonym here; does the tag need to be roasted by Trogdor; or am I all wet?

[image: Trogdor this one?]

Comment: I'm at a loss to why the person would do that. Badges for creating new tags, perhaps?

Comment: Meh, I'd say kill off [zf2]. 1,372 questions with [zend-framework2] seems to indicate that the tag is found just fine.

Comment: Two tags, one question only. Burn them both, they've obviously not been needed until today, and they probably never will be again.

Comment: Both @J.Steen? What is the other one?

Comment: @Bart [tag:drop-down-list]

Comment: I have gone and rolled back to your revision. I have also left a comment to the OP, linking to this discussion, should he wish to make a point about those tags.

Comment: *Crowd shouting* Trogdor Trogdor!

Comment: `zf2` pops up once every other week or so.  It's probably worth making it a synonym.